# Error installing opencv4nodejs on Mac for Appium

Tags: node.js, macos, opencv, npm, appium

I am trying to install the opencv4nodejs on my Mac Monterrey, for the usage of OpenCV with Appium.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/michael/node_modules/opencv4nodejs
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node ./install/install.js
npm ERR! info install using lib dir: /Users/michael/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/build/lib
npm ERR! /Users/michael/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:37
npm ERR!   throw new Error('library dir does not exist: ' + libDir)
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: library dir does not exist: /Users/michael/node_modules/opencv-build/opencv/build/lib
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/michael/node_modules/opencv4nodejs/install/install.js:37:9)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
npm ERR!     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
npm ERR!     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
npm ERR!     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Node.js v18.3.0
```

I get this error message, but I am not sure how to get it to the right path, I tried changing the path, getting different versions of OpenCV, but all results in the same error messages.
I also tried (what feels like all) other Tims on similar installing problems, but no change...
I also tried to deactivate the auto build with
`$ export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1`

I would be glad if someone can help me with that.
I am not to familiar with Mac...

I am using:
npm --version 8.11.0
node --version v18.3.0

Answer (score 0):

try do this

```
$ export OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD=1

$ npm i opencv4nodejs
```

Comment: I did, same result